# Static analysis tool for Javascript geared towards error checking?

Tags: javascript, static-analysis

I know of JSLint/JSHint, but are there JavaScript static analysis tools geared towards error checking rather the syntactical error?

For example:

`new Date(2001, 12, 31)`
This is generally an error, since month in Date constructor is designed to take 0 to 11

`f.apply(arguments)`
This is generally an error since the first argument of apply is `this` context rather than arguments.

`function One(x) { return 1; }
One(1, 2);`

This is generally an error since you are calling a function with known signature of 1 argument  with 2 arguments.

I know what I mentioned are not deterministic, but a lot of the more useful static analysis tools in other languages are not deterministic either. They give confidence rating on the potential error.

Comment: check https://github.com/eslint/eslint , you can define your own rules.

Comment: Check [DeepScan](https://deepscan.io/) (I develop it). It targets to detect possible runtime errors rather than coding convention. For example, it can check [too many arguments](https://deepscan.io/docs/rules/too-many-args) as you mentioned. Try it via your GitHub or in its [Demo](https://deepscan.io/demo/) page.